# Making a simple Image Switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that there are many jQuery scripts ready to implement something like this here that I'm trying to pull together, but I want to make it as simple as possible. Basically when each image thumb of the list is clicked the main image shows the respective image just only bigger.

So, here is my question. Does anyone have a simple script that does that?

```
        <div class="main_image">
           <img src="<?=href['imagem'];?>" /> 
        </div>

        <ul>

            <li>
                <a href="img01.jpg"><img src="img01.jpg" alt="Image Name" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="img02.jpg"><img src="img02.jpg" alt="Image Name" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Should the image open in the browser when clicked?

Comment: No. The idea is to change the image on the main_image div when a list item is clicked. Here is where I'm trying to apply this:

http://www.daterraweb.com/projects/baf/site/?p=available

Comment: Someone else posted a similar question a couple of years later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530158/jquery-image-switcher

Answer (score 3):

it's pretty easy, you can store your thumbnails in a folder called "small" and large images in "large" and then you have something like :

```
<ul>

    <li>
        <img class="small" src="small/img01.jpg" alt="Image Name" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img class="small" src="small/img02.jpg" alt="Image Name" />
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="main_image">
   <img id="large" src="" /> 
</div>
```

and then write something like this :

```
$(".small").click(function(){
var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("small","large");
$("#large").attr("src",src);
})
```

Comment: This is good but I'm actually trying to use the same image for thumbnails and main image. 

I'll just change it on the css.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple, you can actually simplify your code a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/yeGxq/

```
<div class="main_image">
   <img id="main" src="" /> 
</div>

//dont put <a> tags around images because you will just need to cancel navigation    
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="Image Name" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x400" alt="Image Name" />
    </li>
</ul>

//when a list item image is clicked, take your main image and change its src attr
$('li img').click( function() {
    $('#main').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: Maybe he meant use names for the anchors, so visitors could jump to an image?

Comment: Oh, hmm, maybe he wanted the image to open in the browser?

Comment: Here guys.. this is where I'm trying to implement this.. :P

http://www.daterraweb.com/projects/baf/site/?p=available

Comment: @hakim-sina - They are different. Mine doesn't rely on two separate image folders. It merely moves the src attribute from the thumbnail to the main img. I +1'd yours as it is a better solution if you actually have thumbnails. Oh and I actually wrote mine before seeing your answer just in case you think I'm a no good point poacher.

Comment: Just a note for anyone wanting to run the fiddle/use the code, they'll need to update the image files to their own, INCLUDING the main one, which doesn't stay empty, but would either be preset to either a kind of "welcome" page or the first image. Might go without saying since anyone using it would be changing it to their stuff, but some might want to see it working *as written* first, and they won't be able to do that without the tweaks.