# jQuery image switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem**

I'm getting lost reading countless js code hints etc and I'm finding it hard to know where to start. Help!

So basically I have a main full screen background image in the CSS on the `#main` `div` and I have list items each with small thumbnails, when they are clicked they are switched to create a new large background image in the `#main` `div`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <ul id="thumbs">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
    background-image: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/500/50);
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/NjX4n/

Thanks for the help.

---

**Updated Solution**

I managed to solve it in the end using the `data` attribute along with giving each `img` a `class` of `.thumb` for jQuery to interact with.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <ul id="thumbs">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img class="thumb" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50"
                 data-header-img="http://www.lorempixel.com/500/200" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img class="thumb" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50"
                 data-header-img="http://www.lorempixel.com/500/200" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img class="thumb" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50"
                 data-header-img="http://www.lorempixel.com/500/200" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img class="thumb" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/50/50"
                 data-header-img="http://www.lorempixel.com/500/200" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.thumb').click(function() {
    $('#main').css('background-image', "url("+$(this).attr('data-header-img')+")");
});
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/NjX4n/1/

Thanks all the for the input and advice. Y.

Comment: You mean, the background image and the clicked thumbnail image needs to get swapped?

Comment: @YaMo: Just a tip: by adding a `data-header-img` attribute you are making the url of each and every image redundant. You can extract the same data from the `src` attribute of the image directly like: `$(this).attr('src')`.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130859/making-a-simple-image-switcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function like this could do the trick:

```
$('.bgType').click(function (event) {  //class of candidate image  
    var BgUrl = $(this).attr('src'); //identify which image was clicked and get its source
    $('#main').css('background-image', 'url(' + BgUrl + ')'); //set the extracted url as the BG
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4cgCE/3/) is a working example.

I have used jquery for this so don't forget to include jquery in your code.

**UPDATE:**

I have assigned a class to the candidate images for the background. This would prevent any other image being set as the background when clicked.
[find the updated example here](http://jsfiddle.net/4cgCE/4/)

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#"><img class="bgType" src="img1/goes/here.png" /></a>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I managed to solve it in the end. I added a class and to each of the thumbnail images and used the "data-header-img" attribute to hold the large image. Here's the jQuery I managed to get working:
$('.thumb').click(function() { 
$('#main').css('background-image', "url"+$(this).attr('data-header-img')+")"); 
});

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Include id for each  tag

```
<div id="main">
<ul id="thumbs">
<li><a href="#" id="img1"><img src="img1/goes/here.png" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="img2"><img src="img2/goes/here.png" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="img3"><img src="img3/goes/here.png" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="img4"><img src="img4/goes/here.png" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

now you can use click() function to change the background image

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#img1').click(function() {
    //change background image
           $('#main').css('background-image', 'url(img1/goes/here.png)');


            });

//do this for next two links also
        });
    </script>
```